# can't store an object into array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm trying to do something simple and store an object into an Array in C++ but it keeps saying that I can't use the = operator with the right hand operand being of my class. Here's the code:

```
class Player {
    string name;
    double points;
    bool wonLastRound;
public:
    Player() {}
    Player(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    const Player &operator=(const Player &);
    void addPoints(double p)
    {
        points += p;
    }
};
```

and here's the code to instantiate

```
void initPlayers()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        players[i] = new Player("Player " + i);
}
```

any help would be appreciated, I really need to get this project finished soon!

Comment: it's right above the initPlayers method

Comment: How, not where. What's its type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

```
Player& operator = (const Player &);  // remove "const" (it's not mandatory though)
```

**Actual problem lies in assignment** inside `for` loop. You don't have to `new` the objects, as you are storing value and not the pointer.
Usage:

```
players[i] = Player("Player " + i);  // no need to do "new"
```

Comment: Note that the first change (const) is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: There are a lot more problems than this.

Comment: @Rob, yes I was editing it. It's a convention to allow the assignments like "a = b = <value>".

Comment: now my compiler doesn't find any errors but when I click on the button I made in the program later it says the program triggered a breakpoint. I don't know how I let my team mates talk me into doing all this alone, especially in a language I haven't done anything but console applications with.

Comment: @JavaJosh, if you are still finding some problem, then you can post the **relevant** code and make it a new question. So that can be addressed systematically. Thanks.